# Android SDK emulator (AVD) for tablet size

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, tablet

Hi guys i was wondering how to create an emulator environment for a tablet sized device, i know there are quite a few devices being released soon, but how do start sizing up my layout?

thanks

Comment: You should try this:
http://sadkowski.org/sposob-na-wolny-emulator-tabletu-android-4-ice-cream-sandwich This is in polish, but i think if you use google translate you wouldn't had a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy Tab has a 1024×600 resolution. You can easily Google resolutions for other devices that have been announced and create AVDs with matching specs.

You might also want to read up on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Configuration examples:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```